# Create mbean in Mule - monitored by Mule Management Console

Tags: mule, hornetq

We need to monitor HornetQ messaging (part of Jboss) - monitoring is in terms of message arrival in queue, number of messages, messages consumed, auditing message payload. Does HornetQ expose JMX Mbean to monitor this process?

As part of integration strategy this information has to be displayed on Mule Management Console. Mule Management Console can probe only mule instances mbeans. To overcome this we probably need to write custom mbean in Mule which connect to HornetQ messaging, same can be probably displayed on MMC. How do we write custom JMX Mbean on mule and this needs to deployed on to mbean server (agent) and scheduled?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Personally I have never tried this before, but it should be possible to instruct HornetQ using an [MBeanServer bean](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html/management.html#d0e6640) to use [Mule's JMX server](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/JMX+Management).